# Are all units in cover really covered in CoH?

Tags: company-of-heroes

Units in Company of Heroes can be in various kinds of cover. For instance, if the "green cover" symbol appears above a unit group's flag, it means the group is in heavy cover and is hard to hit.

However, does this mean that **the whole group** (any unit in that group) is really in green cover? For instance, is it possible that even though a group's flag shows the green cover symbol only part of its units are really covered while one or two of them are in yellow or no cover?

Comment: I have also wondered this myself.  Sometimes the individual units in a group on screen appear to be out of cover even though the group as a whole is displayed as in cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue the command move there will be a certain color dot on the ground which represents if the specific **unit** is in cover. The color of the **shield represents the overall status of the squad**. E.g if two are out of cover and one is in cover the flag shown will be yellow.

**EDIT:** From my experience the only thing that counts is the color of the dot on the ground, though in the situation you pointed out if you are outnumbered say 2v4 you will lose those two units. When in cover you do take damage, but it will take longer for enemy troops to kill off your units.

Comment: Additional question: Is cover affected by which side of a wall a unit is located? For instance, if all units are in green cover, but on the wrong side of the wall (exposed to the enemy) does the cover still work, or is it utterly useless?

Comment: @mafutrct: If I remember correctly, green cover is directional (so it would be utterly useless if you are on the exposed side), but yellow cover is not directional. This makes sense when you consider green cover is usually walls/objects and yellow cover is usually bushes or fox-holes.